# Variable declaration, does it create a reference to the actual object or a copy?

Tags: c#

I'm looking at the source of a web application and I can see loads of use cases like my sample code below. I can't find any info online about when declaring a local variable in C# (of a complex type) and just want to be sure if it creates a reference or a copy of that object. Coming from a JavaScript background I'd imagine it always creates a reference unless it's a primitive data type.

The code is like this

```
CustomItemType myVarA = (CustomItemType) this.Session["VAR_1"];

// Do some work on the properties of VAR_1
int num2 = checked (myVarA.Items.Count - 1);
int index = 0;
while (index <= num2)
{
    myVarA.Items[index].StatusCode = "Posted";
    checked { ++index; }
}

// Save back to the session
this.Session["VAR_1"] = (object) myVarA;
```

Am I right in thinking that the following line isn't needed.

```
// Save back to the session
this.Session["VAR_1"] = (object) myVarA;
```

As the local variable `myVarA` is just a reference to the property in the session so if you update the local var then you'll also be updating the session object?

Secondly, could this pose a problem when each web page is served in a new thread that these multiple threads will be accessing the same session object and doing manipulations at the same time?

Comment: It depends on `CustomItemType`. If it is a class, then it's a reference type and the save back isn't needed indeed. If it's a structure, it is a value type and you'll get a copy.

Comment: Its prob best to check. session can do some odd things and can have different backing stores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Primitive data types and structures (declared as `struct`) are 'by
   value', clasess (declared as `class`) are 'by reference'. So it
   depends on what `CustomItemType` is.
2. Yes, it pose potential threads synchronization issue. In a simple case you can put object manipulations inside `lock` block.